# how to execute procedure use laravel5.4

Tags: oracle, laravel, procedure

I created a procedure in oracle, then execute the procedure in laravel5.4, but i can't execute it use the following code, in addition to this code, i test the other from google, but it still can't execute, I need your help, thanks very much!

```js
$bindings = [
    'p_bill_code'  => $bill_code,
    'p_bill_inter_id' =>$bill_inter_id,
    'p_user'=>$user
];

$result = DB::executeProcedure($procedureName, $bindings);
```

Comment: What's the problem? Could you provide your error message / stacktrace?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Ok, provide structure of using table with data type.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean, do you mean the structure of input parameter?@AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: Your database table structure which is used into procedure. This is because may be the issue with table column/data type

Comment: it's like this:                                                                                      
create table "bills" 
(
   "id"                 number               not null,
   "code"               nvarchar2(50),
   "name"               nvarchar2(50),
   "fullname"           nvarchar2(100),
   "seq_length"         number,
   "symbol"             nvarchar2(50),
   "is_audit"           number(1),
   "path"               nvarchar2(100),
   "created_user"       number,
   "created_at"         date                 default sysdate,
   constraint pk_bills primary key ("id")
)

Comment: and it throw the error: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedurename. but my input parameter are p_bill_code,p_bill_inter_id and p_user, so i don't known where is wrong.@Alfa

Comment: and it throw the error: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedurename. but my input parameter are p_bill_code,p_bill_inter_id and p_user, so i don't known where is wrong.@Jerodev

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
DB::select('EXEC procedure_name(?,?)',array($Param1,$param2));
```

**Edit**

```
$bindings = [$bill_code,$bill_inter_id,$user];
DB::select('EXEC procedure_name(?,?,?)',$bindings);
```

Comment: I tried, like this $temp=DB::select('EXEC launchAuditPro("p_bill_code","p_bill_inter_id","p_user")',array($bill_code,$bill_inter_id,$user)); but it throws the error: illegal variable name/number.@Abderrahim Soubai Elidrissi

Comment: You have to use question marks (`?`) for the placeholders for values, not names.

Comment: you mean like this?$bingings=['p_bill_code'=>$bill_code,
                'p_bill_inter_id'=>$bill_inter_id,
                'p_user'=>$user];
            $temp=DB::select('EXEC launchAuditPro (?,?,?)',$bingings);，it still throws the error:illegal variable name/number.@Jerodev

Comment: I tried, but it throws the error: invalid SQL statement.@Abderrahim Soubai Elidrissi

Comment: can you sow you code i think you have problems with paramters

Comment: create or replace procedure launchAuditPro(p_bill_code in NVARCHAR2, p_bill_inter_id in NVARCHAR2, p_user in NUMBER) @Abderrahim Soubai Elidrissi

Comment: $user is a number or object ?

Comment: it's a number@AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi

Comment: Try to hardcode DB::select('EXEC launchAuditPro(?,?,?)',['a','b',1]);

Comment: the array should have key, if it has't, it will throw the error:invalid SQL statement, if it has, it throws the erro:illegal variable name/number.@AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi